# JavaScript if else works like checkbox always in initial state

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I can receive a checkbox (blackbox) state like true or false in the browser developer console correctly with `$("#blackbox").prop('checked')`or with `$('#blackbox').is(':checked')`. Tried both.

Let's say I  use `checked` in checkbox `<input type="checkbox" id="blackbox" name="blackbox" title="Enable Something" checked>`

I'll get longform output both with checkbox checked and unchecked. Same happens with empty checkbox `<input type="checkbox" id="blackbox" name="blackbox" title="Enable Something">`, all I can get in the end is short data output both with checked and unchecked checkbox.

What I really want is long output when the checkbox is checked and short output when the checkbox is unchecked.

```
<div class="container">
    <form action="add" id="urlform" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <div class="control-group">
    <div class="input-append">
    <input type="checkbox" id="blackbox" name="blackbox" title="Enable Something">
    <input type="text" id="url" value="" placeholder="Text">
    <input class="btn btn-warning "type="submit" value="Shorten">
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
<form action="/s/add" id="longform" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8"></form>
<script>
var form = $('#urlform');
var form2 = $('#longform');

if ($('#blackbox').is(':checked')) {
    test = form2;
} else {
    test = form;
}
form.submit(function () {
$.ajax({
    type: test.attr('method'),
    url: test.attr('action') + '?url=' + $('#url').val(),
    success: function (data) {
    test.append('<p style="color:#FFA500">' + 'https://' + location.host + '/' +
    data[0].uid + '</p>')
    }
});
return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: You’re checking whether the checkbox is checked and setting the form _only once_. It should be in your submit function.

Comment: You check this when the page loads, it does not automatically update when the checkbox changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if ($('#blackbox').is(':checked')) { ... }` is happening on page load and the `form.submit` is happening multiple times but only using the value that was set on page load.

Move the logic into the `form.submit()` action:

```
<script>
  var form = $('#urlform');
  var form2 = $('#longform');

  form.submit(function () {
    if ($('#blackbox').is(':checked')) {
      test = form2;
    } else {
      test = form;
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: test.attr('method'),
        url: test.attr('action') + '?url=' + $('#url').val(),
        success: function (data) {
          test.append('<p style="color:#FFA500">' + 'https://' + location.host + '/' +
          data[0].uid + '</p>')
        }
    });
    return false;
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have done it differntly... leave your submit() function alone, attach the logic to the checkbox itself.. also shorten it up with some ternary..

```
$('#blackbox').change(function(){
    test = $(this).is(':checked') ? form2 : form;
});
```